# Confused about behaviour of shaders in OpenGL - switching declarations creates errors and crashes

Tags: c++, opengl, input, shader, glfw

I'm creating functions to load shaders, to create meshes, and the like, thus I started a simple program to test the functionalities I was adding, one by one, and I found a problem with this bit:

```
const char* vertexShader = prm.LoadShader ( "simple_vs.glsl" ).c_str ();
const char* fragmentShader = prm.LoadShader ( "simple_fs.glsl" ).c_str ();

GLuint vs = glCreateShader ( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
glShaderSource ( vs, 1, &vertexShader, NULL );
glCompileShader ( vs );
GLuint fs = glCreateShader ( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
glShaderSource ( fs, 1, &fragmentShader, NULL );
glCompileShader ( fs );
```

If I tried to compile it, I would get no errors, but there would be a black screen. If I removed the fragment shader, it would display a triangle, as it was meant to, without any colors. If I switched the two declarations, as in:

```
const char* fragmentShader = prm.LoadShader ( "simple_fs.glsl" ).c_str ();
const char* vertexShader = prm.LoadShader ( "simple_vs.glsl" ).c_str ();
```

I would get an error, and my program would crash:

```
Error code #3: Shader info for shader 1: WARNING: 0:1: '#version' : 
version number deprecated in OGL 3.0 forward compatible context driver
ERROR: 0:1: '#extension' :  'GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects' is not
supported
```

However, if I put it like this:

```
const char* vertexShader = prm.LoadShader ( "simple_vs.glsl" ).c_str ();

GLuint vs = glCreateShader ( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
glShaderSource ( vs, 1, &vertexShader, NULL );
glCompileShader ( vs );

const char* fragmentShader = prm.LoadShader ( "simple_fs.glsl" ).c_str ();

GLuint fs = glCreateShader ( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
glShaderSource ( fs, 1, &fragmentShader, NULL );
glCompileShader ( fs );
```

It works perfectly fine. I am completely clueless as to why this is the case, as I ran the original code with no issues in prior versions of my program. I already checked the *prm.LoadShader* function, it works fine, and returns the expected value. None of the changes I have made to the program deal with shaders, so I am confused about this bizzarely particular behaviour. Can someone with more experience explain why exactly this is happening?

Comment: Besides the error pointed by @Joseph, the shader log message seems pretty clear about the problem. Which `#version` are you adding to the shaders? And which OpenGL version are you targeting? Also, if `GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects` is not available in your machine, you will just have to fall back so old-style shader programs.

Comment: Version 400. The thing is, as I mentioned, that only happens sometimes, that's the point. The issue was how I did things when passing the string containing the shader's text, not OpenGL itself.

Comment: So it was working normally before you changed the shader loading code?

Comment: It was working fine until I started rewriting the code. I have now finished reworking the way I pass the shader to be compiled, and it all works fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably `prm.LoadShader` returns a `std::string` by value. Calling `c_str` gives you the internal character storage of a `std::string`, which only lives as long as the `std::string` does. By the end of each of the `LoadShader` lines, the `std::string` that was returned is destroyed because it was a temporary object, and the pointers you've stored are no longer pointing at valid character arrays.

You can easily get around it by storing a local copy of the returned strings.

```
std::string vertexShader = prm.LoadShader ( "simple_vs.glsl" );
const char* cVertexShader = vertexShader.c_str();
std::string fragmentShader = prm.LoadShader ( "simple_fs.glsl" );
const char* cFragmentShader = vertexShader.c_str();

GLuint vs = glCreateShader ( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
glShaderSource ( vs, 1, &cVertexShader, NULL );
glCompileShader ( vs );
GLuint fs = glCreateShader ( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
glShaderSource ( fs, 1, &cFragmentShader, NULL );
glCompileShader ( fs );
```

Comment: What you said is true, but then how does it work for the last snippet? Wouldn't it still go out of scope? Or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: @MKII It is technically undefined behaviour. However, I imagine the reason it doesn't work when they are together is that the two temporary `std::string`s occupy the same space. When you have the separate, you're just very lucky that the internal string data hangs around in memory long enough.

Comment: I see. I only have a second question: the code you have provided doesn't work, it returns this error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'const GLchar** {aka const char**}' in argument passing

Comment: @MKII Oops, I forgot that it takes an array of strings. I'll fix that.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I had already tried to pass it by reference before you edited your post.

Comment: lvalue required as unary & operand.

Comment: @MKII Can't get away without storing the pointers, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just tried it and it went back to crashing. Guess I will have to do something about it. Thanks anyway, at least now I know what I am doing wrong